# TypeError: _variable_v2_call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initializer' in tensor flow version=2.0.0

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

```
phi = tf.Variable("phi", shape=(k),dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
                             trainable=False)
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-da3533caa9df> in <module>
      3                       dtype=tf.float32,
      4                       initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
----> 5                       trainable=False)
      6 

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\variables.py in __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    258       return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
    259     elif cls is Variable:
--> 260       return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)
    261     else:
    262       return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: _variable_v2_call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initializer'
```

got an unexpected keyword argument 'initializer' in tensor flow version=2.0.0

Comment: Check the signature for tf.Variable(...). I don't think it includes 'initializer' as one of the keyword arguements. tf.Variable(
    initial_value=None, trainable=None, validate_shape=True, caching_device=None,
    name=None, variable_def=None, dtype=None, import_scope=None, constraint=None,
    synchronization=tf.VariableSynchronization.AUTO,
    aggregation=tf.compat.v1.VariableAggregation.NONE, shape=None
)

Answer (score 2):

Use this `tf.compat.v1.get_variable` instead of `tf.Variable`. This works with tensorflow 2.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Use this (the initializer is deprecated in tensorflow 2.0):

```
phi = tf.Variable(
  "phi",
  shape=(k),
  dtype=tf.float32,
  tf.zeros_initializer(),
  trainable=False)
```